# Could PureAttribute only be guaranteed when manipulating primitive types?

Tags: c#, resharper, static-analysis, code-contracts, pure-function

JetBrains annotations:

> Indicates that a method does not make any observable state changes.
>   The same as System.Diagnostics.Contracts.PureAttribute

Microsoft Code Contracts:

> Indicates that a type or method is pure, that is, it does not make
>   any visible state changes.

When operating with primitive types it is very easy to know if your method is a pure function or not.

Consider this scenario however:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dodgy = new DodgyClass();

        string.Format("{0}", dodgy);
    }
}

public class DodgyClass
{
    public int State = 0;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        State = new Random().Next();
        return State.ToString();
    }
}
```

ReSharper tells me that "return value of pure method is not used" which is obviously incorrect since the state does change and in a very visible way. Unless of course they mean that any static method is always pure? Otherwise none of LINQ extension methods are pure since I can do all sort of state manipulation when overriding GetEnumerator().

Comment: I think it's indicating that `string.Format` *should* be pure... which would be the case if your `ToString` method were pure, which is assumed to be the case by default, I believe.

Comment: The language both of them are using in their documentation is stronger then "should" and that confuses me.

Comment: Sure. It's a matter of one contract relying on another, effectively :(

Comment: @JonSkeet do you want to post it as an answer?